# scalaj-http - 'execute' method is returninig "stream is closed"

Tags: scala, stream, scalaj-http

I want to use the scalaj-http library to download a byte content file with 31gb size from a http connection. 'asBytes' is not an option because it retuns a byte array.

I tried to use the 'execute' method returning an input stream, but when I execute the program bellow it returns that the stream is closed. I don't think that I am reading the stream twice.

What I am doing wrong?

```
  val response: HttpResponse[InputStream] = Http(url).postForm(parameters).execute(inputStream => inputStream)

  if (response.isError) println(s"Sorry, error found: ${response.code}")
  else {
    val is: InputStream = response.body
    val buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
    val fos = new FileOutputStream("xxx")
    var read: Int = 0

    while (read >= 0) {
      read = is.read(buffer)
      if (read > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read)
      }
    }
    fos.close()
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot export the `inputStream` as the stream will be closed at the end of the execute method.
You should use the stream inside the execute, like this :

```
  val response = Http(url).postForm(parameters).execute { is =>         
    val buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
    val fos = new FileOutputStream("xxx")
    var read: Int = 0

    while (read >= 0) {
      read = is.read(buffer)
      if (read > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read)
      }
    }
    fos.close()
  }

  if (response.isError) println(s"Sorry, error found: ${response.code}")
```